# How do I solve this problem with while loop

Tags: python, loops, math, while-loop

`c0=int(input("enter a number here"))`

Question:

1. take any non-negative and non-zero integer number and name it c0;
2. if it's even, evaluate a new c0 as c0 ÷ 2;
3. otherwise, if it's odd, evaluate a new c0 as 3 × c0 + 1;
4. if c0 ≠ 1, skip to point 2
5. Write a program which reads one natural number and executes the above steps as long as c0          remains different from 1
6. We also want you to count the steps needed to achieve the goal. Your code should output all the intermediate values of c0, too.

My code:

```
c01=c0%2
c02=3*c0+1
while c0!=1:
    if c01==0:
        print(c01)
    else:
        print(c02)
    c0+=1
print("total number steps",)
```

Sample input: 16

Expected output:

```
8
4
2
1
steps = 4
```

Comment: Please use backtick `\`` next time to format your code.

Comment: What problem is it you want solved? How does the problem manifest which you observe? Does executing your code have any unwanted behaviour?

Comment: i want it to identify an a number, if even, it should divide the  number by 2 and if odd, it should multiply by 3 and add 1. It should continue until the number inputted becomes 1.i want to know how many cycles of loops needed till the number becomes 1 and everything should be printed out

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    c0 = int(input("Enter a Number Here: "))
    if c0 > 0:
        break
    else:
        continue

count = 0

while c0 != 1:
    if c0 % 2 == 0:
        c0 = c0 / 2
        print("{} ".format(int(c0)))
    else:
        c0 = 3 * c0 + 1
        print("{} ".format(int(c0)))
    count += 1

print("Steps: {}".format(count))
```